# DismissSoftInput() for search-bar for Nativescript-Vue

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

Explaining the problem:

> The search-bar has no way of dismissing an open keyboard. This makes
>   the search-bar a quite unusable as the normal user pattern is that the
>   user search for something and then press the item and gets navigated
>   there. On Android (at least on >= 5.x), the open keyboard will
>   continue to stay open, even on the new page.

Referring to the question on [Github](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/849), anyone how to do that for Nativescript-Vue and not for Nativescript with Typescript

## Updated:

Added Playground: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=hrrcW9

If I minimize the app, then click on it again, the keyboard pops open again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you could already see in the linked issue, the feature request is closed as completed. [dismissSoftInput()](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_search_bar_.searchbar#dismisssoftinput) is a method on SearchBar now that hides the keyboard.

If you have issues still, please share your code.

**Update:**

It's the default behaviour of Android to focus first focusable element on fragment / activity. Adding event listeners / timeouts to remove focus from each screen might be annoying, I would prefer using a auto focus view as first element (which will not have any impact on the screen design) of my layout, that would prevent auto focusing on my text fields / search bar.

```
import { View } from "tns-core-modules/ui/core/view";

export class AutoFocusView extends View {

    createNativeView() {
        if (typeof android !== "undefined") {
            const linearLayout = new android.widget.LinearLayout(this._context);
            linearLayout.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            linearLayout.setFocusable(true);
            return linearLayout;
        }
        return super.createNativeView();
    }

    onLoaded() {
        super.onLoaded();
        if (typeof android !== 'undefined') {
            this.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    requestFocus() {
        if (typeof android !== "undefined") {
            const nativeViewProtected = this.nativeViewProtected;
            nativeViewProtected.requestFocus();
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=JeMq3c&v=2)

Comment: I don't see any issue with Playground sample, the keyboard stays hidden.

Comment: If you press the middle (or Home) Button does "minimize" the App. There after reopen the minimized app, the keyboard will pop-up again.

Comment: It's the default behaviour of Android to focus first focusable element on fragment / activity. The timeout interval was not quite enough when you resume from background, of course it could be annoying using timeout and stuffs. I usually prefer including a dummy auto focus view as first element on my layout, so my text fields / search bars won't be focus at all unnecessarily. I will update your Playground shortly.

Comment: @Manoj but if I use this I will get errors on ios since there is no linearLayout in IOS. Would you please update your answer so that people can use it without getting errors on ios?

Comment: The answer is already considering iOS too, `if (typeof android !== "undefined") { }`. May be you would need the same check in `requestFocus()` method too.